# Kafka, Schema Registry: IP vs exposed url connection problem

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to get the messages from Kafka

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --consumer.config consumer.properties --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 
--topic kafka_topic --from-beginning --max-messages 5 --property schema.registry.url=https://my-url.pl
```

and getting error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: 
Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 6
Caused by:
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:
Unrecognized token 'error': was expecting 
(JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream);
line: 1, column: 7]; error code: 50005
```

which points that there is no connection to Schema Registry (error instead of schema).

But the strange thing is, if I change the url to IP of Schema Registry, it works:

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --consumer.config consumer.properties --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 
--topic kafka_topic --from-beginning --max-messages 5  --property schema.registry.url=http://x.x.x:8081

{"message"}
```

there is connection from my pod in both ways:

```
curl http://x.x.x:8081
{}

curl https://my-url.pl
{}

curl http://x.x.x:8081/schemas/ids/6
{"schema":"...}

curl https://my-url.pl/schemas/ids/6
{"schema":"...}
```

The problem is, the Schema Registry is deployed on K8S so its IP will be changig, that is why I need to connect via exposed url...
Do you have any idea what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

> `Unrecognized token 'error'`

This suggest that the HTTP client used by the console consumer is not getting valid JSON. You'll want to inspect the Schema Registry's server logs to identify the issue

The client also uses `/subjects/<topic>-value/versions/<version>` call, not just `/schemas/ids`

> so its IP will be changing

You should use a Service/Ingress name, rather than an IP. If your IngressContoller is misconfigured, then you would expect the Ingress server (e.g. Nginx) to not return a valid response.

Answer (score -1):

You can get more information changing logging level with and you can see the call to schemaRegistry

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web: ERROR
        kafka: debug
    io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService: debug
```

Comment: `kafka-avro-console-consumer` in the OP doesn't use Spring. This will only work if you've written your own Spring service that uses the Confluent Deserializer